# Do multiple promises on an array of elements

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, promise, bluebird

I have a list of objectIds and I want to go to different collections and do operations base on each Id. I would prefer doing the operation one after the other (sequentially)

```
var removeOperation = function(objectified){
   return Comps.findOne({reviews : objectified}).populate([{ path: "reviews", match : {_id : objectified}}])

}
var firstCheckIfAnonHasTheIdInReviewsArrayIfThereDeleteIt = function(objectified){
    var query = {reviews : objectified};
    var update = {$pull : {reviews : objectified}};
    var option = {new :true};
    return Anon.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, option );
};
var thenCheckIfUserHasTheIdInReviewsArrayIfThereDeleteIt = function(objectified){
    var query = {reviews : objectified};
    var update = {$pull : {reviews : objectified}};
    var option = {new :true};
    return User.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, option );
}
```

I was going down this path:

```
Promise.mapSeries(arrOfObjectIds, function(e){
    return removeOperation(e);
})
.then(function(results){
    console.log(results);
    var map = results.map(function(e){
        // return e.reviews[0]
        return e

    })
    console.log("map : ", map)
    return Promise.resolve(map);
})
.then(function(compDocs){
    console.log("compDocs: ",compDocs)
    Promise.mapSeries(compDocs,  function(compDoc){
        return updateCompAndRemoveReviewFromArray(compDoc) // I know it's not show. It's another promise I use
    })

}).then(function(returned){
    return Reviews.remove({_id : {$in : arrOfObjectIds }})
})
.then(function(){
  I wanted to do firstCheckIfAnonHasTheIdInReviewsArrayIfThereDeleteIt on the array of object Ids to delete the review from the array. Also if we succesfully removed the array here we should not have to go to the next user 
  promise which deletes a users review since if we deleted in Anon it won't be in User. since there is only one review ID possible per review.
})
.then(function(){
    //if there was no review pulled from the Anon reviews Array. that means it's in the users review and we should do this promise 

       thenCheckIfUserHasTheIdInReviewsArrayIfThereDeleteIt()
})
```

So maybe you can show me how to use `mapSeries` on an array of elements so that it just doesn't d one promise but does multiple promises.

can we doe something like:

```
Promise.mapSeries(arrOfObjectIds, function(e){
    return removeOperation(e);
    return firstCheckIfAnonHasTheIdInReviewsArrayIfThereDeleteIt(e)// extra credit: check if this was successful (review was pulled). If it wasn't got to next one.
    return thenCheckIfUserHasTheIdInReviewsArrayIfThereDeleteIt(e)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Restating the problem in simplified terms :

> You have an array of IDs and for each ID in turn you want to call three promise-returning functions, `A`, `B` and `C` as follows :
>
> - `A(id)` (unconditionally)
> - then `B(id)` (unconditionally)
> - then `C(id)` (conditionally, depending on the outcome of `B(id)`)

---

> Can we do something like:

```
Promise.mapSeries(arrOfObjectIds, function(e){
    return removeOperation(e);
    return firstCheckIfAnonHasTheIdInReviewsArrayIfThereDeleteIt(e)// extra credit: check if this was successful (review was pulled). If it wasn't got to next one.
    return thenCheckIfUserHasTheIdInReviewsArrayIfThereDeleteIt(e)
})
```

Yes, though *not very* like the suggested code.

First, you have a design choice concerning the way in which `B` reports its outcome. The question hints at B's outcome being a case of "success" vs "failure", but that's not the only way to model it.

**Option 1: Test data delivered down the promise chain's success path**

Write `B` such that its returned promise will fulfill both on success (Anon review was deleted) or on the *expected* failure (Anon review was not deleted), and report the outcome by means of a parameter.

```
var B = function(objectified) {
    var query = {reviews: objectified};
    var update = {$pull: {reviews: objectified}};
    var option = {new :true};
    return Anon.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, option).exec();
};
```

Then you would write :

```
Promise.mapSeries(arrOfObjectIds, function(id) {
    return A(id).then(function() {
        return B(id);
    }).then(function(item) { // item will be `null` if B(id) found nothing.
        return item || C(id);
    }).catch(function(error) {
        // If anything went wrong, catch the error and log it.
        console.log(error); 
        // By not re-throwing the error, the mapseries() is allowed to continue.
    });
});
```

**Option 2: Test error delivered down the promise chain's failure path**

Write `B` such that its returned promise will fulfill on success, or reject on expected failure.

```
var B = function(objectified) {
    var query = {reviews: objectified};
    var update = {$pull: {reviews: objectified}};
    var option = {new :true};
    return Anon.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, option).exec().then(function(item) {
        return item || Promise.reject(new Error('not found'));
    });
};
```

Then you would write :

```
Promise.mapSeries(arrOfObjectIds, function(id) {
    return A(id).then(function() {
        return B(id).catch(function(error) {
            // Here, you have to discriminate between the "expected error" and any unexpected errors.
            if(error.message === 'not found') {
                return C(id);
            } else {
                throw error; // unexpected error - rethrow it
            }
        });
    }).catch(function(error) {
        // If anything went wrong, catch the error and log it.
        console.log(error); 
        // By not re-throwing the error, the overall mapseries() is allowed to continue.
    });
});
```

In both options :

- to return a genuine Promise, use `.exec()` in `A`, `B` and `C`. (As I understand Mongoose, without `exec()` you get something which has a `.then()` method, but which is not a full-blown Promise).
- if you want the overall sequence to stop on first error, then rethrow the error after logging it, or completely omit the final `catch()`.
- further unconditional stages can be added very simply, before or after the conditional stage.

For me, Option 2 is more logical, though I would probably choose Option 1 for its greater simplicity and efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.reduce()` to execute your promises in series:

```
arrOfObjectIds.reduce(function(promise, objectId) {
  return promise.then(function(result) {
    return removeOperation(objectId)
      .then(firstCheckIfAnonHasTheIdInReviewsArrayIfThereDeleteIt)
      .then(thenCheckIfUserHasTheIdInReviewsArrayIfThereDeleteIt);
  });
}, Promise.resolve());
```

This will perform the chain of `removeOperation -> firstCheck.. -> thenCheck` one item in the array at a time, then move to the next item.

Answer (score 0):

`can we doe something like:` yes, like that, except the first return exits the function

so, you could possibly do something like

```
Promise.mapSeries(arrOfObjectIds, function(e){
    return removeOperation(e)
    .then(function() {
        return firstCheckIfAnonHasTheIdInReviewsArrayIfThereDeleteIt(e);
    }).then(function() {
        return thenCheckIfUserHasTheIdInReviewsArrayIfThereDeleteIt(e);
    })
})
```